# MVC Web Api 404 Bad Request

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, bad-request

I have a problem about MVC WebAPi. Here some information from my project.

WebApiConfig;

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{no}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, no = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

TapuZeminApiController;

```
// GET api/<controller>
    [Route("api/TapuZeminApi/GetZemins")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string GetZeminsFromZeminArg(object arg)
    {
        ZeminArg zemArg = SConvert.DeserializeJSON<ZeminArg>(arg.ToString());

        List<TapuZeminModel> zeminList = TapuModule.GetZeminListFromArgs(zemArg);


        string jsonResult = SConvert.SerializeJSON(zeminList);
        return jsonResult;
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string GetZeminsFromTcNo(int id)
    {
        List<TapuZeminModel> zeminList = TapuModule.GetZeminListFromTcNo(id.ToString());

        string jsonResult = SConvert.SerializeJSON(zeminList);
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

And i have another a lot of Api like;

TapuParselApiController;

```
public List<string> GetAdaNo(int id)
    {
        List<string> adaList = TapuModule.GetAdaListFromMahalleTapuKod(id);

        adaList = adaList.OrderBy(x => x, new AlphanumComparator()).ToList();
        return adaList;
    }

   [Route("Api/TapuParselApi/GetParselNo/MahalleId/{id}/AdaNo/{adaNo}")]
    public object GetParselNo(int id, string adaNo)
    {
        List<TapuParselModel> parselList = TapuModule.GetParselListFromMahalleAndAdaTapuKod(id, adaNo);

        List<string> parselNoList = parselList.Select(x => x.ParselNo).ToList<string>();
        parselNoList = parselNoList.OrderBy(x => x, new AlphanumComparator()).ToList();

        var jsonResult = SConvert.SerializeJSON(parselNoList);
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

I can use all of api but one of them not working. When i tried to reach

```
http://localhost:55591/Api/TapuZeminApi/GetZeminsFromTcNo/41206410132
```

it returns

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

The request is invalid.

```
<MessageDetail>
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String GetZeminsFromTcNo(Int32)' in 'Sehir.Catalog.Areas.Tapu.Controllers.TapuZeminApiController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Why is getting this error?? What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://localhost:55591/Api/TapuZeminApi/GetZeminsFromTcNo/41206410132
```

The value *41206410132* in this http request is too large for an `int`.

You need to change the parameter type in your controller action to a `long`.

```
    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string GetZeminsFromTcNo(long id)
    {
        List<TapuZeminModel> zeminList = TapuModule.GetZeminListFromTcNo(id.ToString());

        string jsonResult = SConvert.SerializeJSON(zeminList);
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

You can read more about the limits of numeric types [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/296az74e.aspx).